# Return Post ID from WP_Meta_query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to get the post_id column after running this code:

```
$query_args = array (
        array(
            'key' => 'registration',
            'value' => $reg,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    );

    $query = new WP_Meta_Query($query_args);
```

How can I retrieve the post_id for the post please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [get_the_ID()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) like this:

$post_id = get_the_ID();